# Is quotient of a matrix group still a matrix group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory

I can't think of any counterexample but can't prove either.

Comment: No -- the elements of a quotient are cosets, not matrices.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a counterexample. Let $H$ be the real Heisenberg group

$$H=\left\{\begin{pmatrix} 1 & a & b\newline 0&1&c\newline 0 &0 &1\end{pmatrix} \hspace{0.5em}\middle|\hspace{0.5em} a,b,c\in\mathbb{R} \right\}.$$

This is a matrix group, i.e., a linear group. Now let
$\Gamma$ be the discrete subgroup

$$\Gamma=\left\{\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & n\newline0&1&0\newline 0 &0 &1\end{pmatrix} \hspace{0.5em}\middle|\hspace{0.5em} n\in\mathbb{Z} \right\}.$$

The subgroup $\Gamma$ is central, and thus normal. The Lie group $H/\Gamma$ has no faithful finite dimensional representations over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$. Hence it is not linear, i.e., it is not a matrix group.